# Whispersync-like experience for PDF or TXT files?

Tags: iphone, mac, ios, pdf, text

When I start reading a PDF or TXT on my Mac and continue reading it on my iPhone, I have to waste time looking for exact place where I stopped reading on my Mac before continuing to read on my iPhone.

Is there a web-based app or a Mac/iOS app that would remember where I left off, the way Whispersync does in the Kindle app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Voice Dream](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/voice-dream-reader/id496177674?mt=8) iOS app was updated to version 4.0 which includes a new feature that will save reading locations to multiple devices using iCloud.

Here's a quote from their notes on what's new in 4.0.

> Library Synchronization • Your entire library, including folders,
>   reading locations, bookmarks and annotations are synchronized across
>   all your devices using iCloud Drive.

Voice Dream is meant as a text-to-speech app, but it also works well for times you want to read PDFs and other text without speech.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options you could check out:

1. [Instapaper](http://instapaper.com/)

   - Acts a lot like Whispersync for any article you find on the web.
   - You can read via a nice iOS app or the web app.
   - You can also forward txt into your Instapaper account via email.
   - It's supported by a ton of [additional iOS apps](http://www.instapaper.com/extras).
   - You can use actually link it right into your Kindle natively through Instapaper or using [Ephemera](http://goephemera.com/).
   - It does NOT do PDF that I am aware of.
2. [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com/)

   - A slick app to sync text files across devices including your Mac and iOS devices.
   - It has lots of [third party support](http://simplenoteapp.com/downloads/).
   - It does not do PDF or any of the Whispersync-like reading progress syncing.
3. [Good Reader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html) + [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)

   - You can sync PDFs and other eBook formats easily between your Mac and iOS devices using Dropbox.
   - This solution will NOT do the Whispersync-like reading progress syncing.

As far as I have seen I think Instapaper is going to be your best option for getting a very similar experience to what you're looking for.

Comment: This is very thorough. Also, now Kindle's app let's you Whispersync non-Amazon files.